# fetch multiple records in mysql and store it into json array display in the HTML table single single field

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, json

I am fetching multiple records from database and try to store into json array, but the only last record will get stored into array. How to store multiple data into an json array.
And I have to display this array in HTML table single single field.

```
$data11 = mysql_query($sql1);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data11)) {  
  $data["names"] = $row["name"];
}
echo json_encode($data);

 $.ajax({
     data:{durationBaseLinetest:durationBaseLinetest, baseline_data:baseline_data, customDate2:customDate2, customDate1:customDate1 },
     type:"POST",
     url:"testing.php",
     // dataType:"html",
     dataType:"JSON",
     success: function(data){
         $('#names').text(data.datatime); 
     }
 });
```

Comment: can you format the code and show the complete code?

Comment: Welcome. Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they're deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead

Comment: In your `while` loop you're overwriting `$data["names"]` with every iteration, that's why you only get the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how todo it, add every single row as an array, so you have an array of arrays. Also i would suggest you switch to mysqli library instead of mysql because of security reasons and the fact it is not beeing maintained.

```
mysql_query($sql1);
$data = [];
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data11)){
   $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: In this code get complete array then how to display single data by the field name just like (name,datetime)

Comment: `echo $row['name']; echo $row['datetime'];`

Comment: echo $row[0]['name']; echo $row[0]['datetime'].

Comment: when outside of a loop yes

Comment: How to display data in required page that we get through this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below Code:

```
$data11 = mysql_query($sql1);
$data = [];
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data11)) {  
  $data[]["names"] = $row["name"];
}
```

Comment: Would be more useful if you added what you changed/added and why OP should use this code.

Comment: In this code get complete array then how to display single data by the field name just like (name,datetime)??